# Hibernate: on-delete="noaction" is ignored

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using hibernate (3.6.0) Join relation to map OneToOne relation between user and its external representation.

Due to performance guidance we used Join instead of one-to-one mapping. The problem is 
whenever ExternalUser deleted, Hibernate deletes also the InternalUser 

 despite of

> on-delete="noaction" 
>   
> which according to hibernate reference disables cascade delete.
>   
>  section 5.1.21. Key: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html

The Mapping of the classes:

```
<class name="com.example.ExternalUser" table="externalusers" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" schema="mySchema">
  <id name="externalUserGuid" >
    <column  name="externalUserGuid"  sql-type="uniqueidentifier"/> <generator class="guid"/>
  </id>
  <property name="id"    column="Id" update="false"/>
  <property name="name"    column="Name"/>
  <property name="lastName"    column="LastName"/>
  <join table="users" optional="true" schema="mySchema" >
    <key   column="GUID" on-delete="noaction" update="false"/> 
    <property name="userId" column="Id" update="false" />       
  </join>         
</class>


<class name="com.example.InternalUser" table="users" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" schema="mySchema">
  <id name="id" column="Id">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>    
  <property name="userName" column="UserName" />    
  <property name="password" column="Password" />    
  <property name="registrationStatus" column="Enabled" />
  <property name="unlockedAt" column="UnlockedAt" />
  <property name="registeredAt" column="RegisteredAt" />
```

If I'll add inverse attribute to Join tag it would solve the issue, however I would like to understand why on-delete="noaction" was ignored by hibernate.

Comment: What are the SQL's fired when you call session.delete(externalUser) is called?

Comment: First `Delete InternalUser where  GUID = P0`, then another SQL with `Delete ExternalUser' where  Id= P0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the Inverse. As default Inverse on a relationship is false. the meaning of the inverse property is basically who is the owner of the relationship.

In your example Hibernate sees InternalUser as the owner of the relationship. so when you delete ExternalUser Hibernate decides that InternalUser has no need to exist since it is one-to-one relationship and the owner is InternalUser.

So you will a deletion of InternalUser and then ExternalUser.

Try to add an Inverse=true on you relationship and see if the behavior changes...